# GWT in IE8 - Exception thrown and not caught

Tags: internet-explorer, gwt

I have posted this on the Google Web Toolkit Discussion Group but hopefully you guys can help me. I have built a GWT application which runs perfectly in Firefox and Chrome.

When attempting to load it up in Internet Explorer 8 I get the error from one of my generated cache.html files:

Line: 408
Char: 12
Error: Exception thrown and not caught.
Code: 0

When I locate that line in the generated file (this was all done with the -PRETTY argument for easy reading) I find it's on the line where the finally is at:

```
function entry0(jsFunction, thisObj, arguments_0){
  var initialEntry;
  initialEntry = entryDepth++ == 0;
  try {
    return jsFunction.apply(thisObj, arguments_0);
  }
  finally {
    initialEntry && $flushFinallyCommands(($clinit_16() , INSTANCE));
    --entryDepth;
  }
}
```

The only problem is that this is not code generated from my client side java - it seems to be GWT's own generated code.

As a test I added an empty catch block - that now stops Internet Explorer from complaining but still doesn't load my application up at all. All that loads is the surrounding html and images and a blank space where my app should be.

Has anyone experienced this before? Any ideas on how to tackle this?

Any information will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,

Xandel

Comment: Just a note to anyone experiencing the same problem - I have found a nice site which describes potential fixes for symptoms found with GWT 2.0.3 (the version I am currently running) and the major browsers such as the page not loading up at all etc. You can check it out here - http://bitbar.com/blog/36/fixing-gwt-20-problems-ie-ff-and-opera. Will look into it and post again if that now allows my site to load up, as for the uncaught exception error - haven't had any luck with that yet.

Comment: Can you provide any details about the uncaught exception itself? Knowing what the exception is would help. Code that reproduces the problem would be even better.

Comment: I haven't actually checked the exception - I was under the impression that it was more a "compilation error" on IE's part - as in the syntax is incorrect, not that it's throwing an actual exception... I am back on this now and am hunting for a fix. Will attempt to display the exception in the event that what you're saying is right. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I decided to set up a simple Windows development machine enabling me to debug the application on IE. The problem jumped out straight away with an error message in development mode...

```
flexTable.getFlexCellFormatter().setWidth(row, 1, "0px");
```

GWT was not happy with "0px" being passed as a parameter... I was trying to "hide" a column temporarily.